# TypeScript errors in React Class Component property does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>', not sure how to set types for state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React Class Component with two properties in state. I'm currently getting a TypeScript error when trying to dynamically setState that says `Property 'input' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'`.

I'm newer to TypeScript and I haven't yet had to tackle the problem of adding Type definitions to a Class Component before. I've been working mostly with functional components and hooks so this issue hasn't come up for me.

I defined the type for my App State and then passed it into the component, but I'm still getting the original error as well as a new error where I define state that says `'AppState' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

I've been searching around for a solution but haven't been able to solve this.

`My original component`

```
type AppState = {
  input: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}

class App extends Component<AppState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    // Error: 'AppState' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
    this.state: AppState = {
      input: "",
      imageUrl: "",
    };
  }

  onInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  };

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    // Error: Property 'input' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.
    this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input });
    clarifaiApp.models
      .predict(
        Clarifai.COLOR_MODEL,
        // URL
        "https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg"
      )
      .then(
        function (response: any) {
          console.log("This is your response: ", response);
        },
        function (err: Error) {
          console.log("There was an error: ", err);
        }
      );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <ImageLinkForm
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
        />
        {/* Error: Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'. */}
        <FaceRecognition imageUrl={this.state.imageUrl} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For React class components, you will generally need to supply the generic prop parameters with the types for the **props** and **state** respectively.

```
class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {

  ...

}
```

For your case, since there are no props for the `App` component, you will only need to do this:

```
class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state: AppState = {
      input: "",
      imageUrl: "",
    };
  }    
  ...

}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Strangely enough I was still getting an error at ```this.state: AppState = {...}``` so I removed ```AppState``` to change it to this ```this.state = {...}``` and it works!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to initialize the state inside the `constructor` of a class component you have to provide two type argument to the `React.Component` generic. The first argument is meant to provide type information about the props and the second argument is meant to provide the type information about the `state`. For example,

```
interface AppProps {
  // props 
}

type AppState = {
  input: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}

class App extends Component<AppProps,AppState> {
  // you don't need any more explicit type annotation here
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: "",
      imageUrl: "",
    };
  }

  // rest of the app logic
}
```

This would not have caused any issue if you would have initialized the state in the state field outside the constructor.

```js
type AppState = {
  input: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}

class App extends Component {
  state: AppState = {
    input: "",
    imageUrl: ""
  }


  // rest of the app logic
}
```

In the second case, you can choose to provide a type argument for the props if the component is expecting some props. For example,

```js
interface AppProps {
  // type info for props
}

type AppState = {
  input: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}

class App extends Component<AppProps> {
   state: AppState = {
      input: "",
      imageUrl: ""
   }

   // rest of the app logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to try it with the hooks then you can do this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface AppState {
  input: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}

const App: React.FC<AppState> = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");

  const handleOnButtonSubmit = () => {
    setImageUrl(input);
    clarifaiApp.models
      .predict(
        Clarifai.COLOR_MODEL,
        // URL
        "https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg"
      )
      .then(
        function(response: any) {
          console.log("This is your response: ", response);
        },
        function(err: Error) {
          console.log("There was an error: ", err);
        }
      );
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <ImageLinkForm
        onInputChange={(e: any) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        onButtonSubmit={handleOnButtonSubmit}
      />
      <FaceRecognition imageUrl={imageUrl} />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```